# how to iterate over hours in timestamp in python

Tags: python, datetime, for-loop

I'm trying to iterate over the number of hours between two timestamps. for example:

```
a = 2018-01-19 12:35:00 
b = 2018-01-19 18:50:00

for hour in range(a.hour, b.hour +1):
    print(hour)
```

This will reult in: `12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18`

Later on I want to use the 'hour' var, so I need it to count how many hours difference is there, and not the hours themselves..

The result I want is: `0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6`

There another issue when getting timestamps like those:

```
c = 2018-01-16 17:59:00 
d = 2018-01-17 00:14:00
```

because the hour in: `00:14:00` is `0`.

in this case I want to get: `0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7`

I don't know how to do this.. can anyone help please?

Comment: The word/function you are looking for is `enumerate`.

Comment: Thanks! But unfortunately, that solves only the first part of my question... Can you find a way to help with what should I do when the hour is 0?

Comment: what should happen if there is less than one hour difference between the timestamps?

Comment: that is already taken care of.. thanks

Answer (score 1):

The object you want is a "timedelta" object- it represents the duration between 2 timestamps. Say you wanted to start at a date object, and then do something every one hour after that. Don't try to figure out the interval logic yourself, use the built in stuff.

```
>>> a = datetime.now()
>>> a
datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 17, 6, 33, 25, 529995)
>>> a + timedelta(hours=1)
datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 17, 7, 33, 25, 529995)
>>> a + timedelta(hours=1)
datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 17, 7, 33, 25, 529995)
>>> a + timedelta(hours=2)
datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 17, 8, 33, 25, 529995)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
from datetime import datetime

def date_range(x, y):
    fmt = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
    x, y = datetime.strptime(x, fmt), datetime.strptime(y, fmt)
    duration = y.replace(minute=59) - x.replace(minute=0)
    days, seconds = duration.days, duration.seconds
    hours = days * 24 + seconds // 3600
    return list(range(hours + 1))

a = '2018-01-19 12:35:00' 
b = '2018-01-19 18:50:00'
c = '2018-01-16 17:59:00'
d = '2018-01-17 00:14:00'

print(date_range(a, b))
print(date_range(c, d))
```

**Output:**

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```